# Using trim() in Java to remove parts of an ouput

Tags: java, bufferedreader, trim

I have some code I wrote that outputs a batch file output to a jTextArea. Currently the batch file outputs an active directory query for the computer name, but there is a bunch of stuff that outputs as well that I want to be removed from the output from the variable String trimmedLine. Currently it's still outputting everything else and I can't figure out how to get only the computer name to appear.

Output: "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET"

I want the output to instead just show only this:

```
FDCD111304
```

Can anyone show me how to fix my code to only output the computer name and nothing else?
Look at console output (Ignore top line in console output)
[image: Look at console output]

```
    btnPingComputer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String line;
            BufferedWriter bw = null;
            BufferedWriter writer =null;
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String lineToRemove = "OU=Workstations";
            String s = null;
            Process p = null;

            try {

                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\computerQuery.bat");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer(); // new trial
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                    .getInputStream()));

            try {

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println(line);

                    textArea.append(line);
                    textArea.append(String.format("  %s%n", line));
                    sbuffer.append(line + "\n");
                    s = sbuffer.toString();
                    String trimmedLine = line.trim();
                    if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
                    writer.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                fw.write("commandResult is " + s);
                 String input = "CN=FDCD511304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\=(.*?)\\,");
                    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

                    while(m.find()) {

                        String currentVar = m.group().substring(3, m.group().length() - 1);
                        System.out.println(currentVar); //store or do whatever you want
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally

            {
                try {
                    fw.close();

                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try {

                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: You need to use substring

Comment: @user6680 It is your computer name always in the first position of the String?

Comment: Yes it is Error404, but the CN= will always be there before it.

Comment: It looks like you've updated your question with code from one of the answers so that it now uses fixed input and not `line` or `trimmedLine`, this is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `javax.naming.ldap.LdapName` when dealing with distinguished names. It also handles escaping which is tricky with regex alone (i.e. cn=foo\,bar,dc=fl,dc=net is a perfectly valid DN)

```
String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
String commonName = (String) ldapName.getRdn(ldapName.size() - 1).getValue();
```

Comment: I won't have be able to test this until Friday, but you are saying that this  ldapName.getRdn(ldapName.size() - 1).getValue(); will output: "FDCD111304"? If yes and if I'm understanding this then does that mean if I change value 1 in that line of code to a 4, then it will output the user name?

Comment: Yes, assuming that SIM is the user name.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would personally use the split() function to first get the parts split up and then parse out again. So my (probably unprofessional and buggy code) would be

```
String args[] = line.split(",");
String args2[] = args[0].split("=");
String computerName = args2[1];
```

And that would be where this is:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line);
                String trimmedLine = line.trim();
                if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove))
                    continue;
                writer.write(line
                        + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                textArea.append(trimmedLine);
                textArea.append(String.format("  %s%n", line));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different regular expression and `Matcher.matches()` to find only the value you're looking for:

```
String str = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:.*,)?CN=([^,]+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No value for CN found");
}
```

> FDCD111304

That regular expression will find the value for CN regardless of where in the string it is. The first group is to discard anything in front of *CN=* (we use a group starting with `?:` here to indicate that the contents of the group should not be kept), then we match *CN=*, then the value, which may not contain a comma and then the rest of the string (which we don't care about).

You can also use a different regex and `Matcher.find()` to get both the keys and values and choose which keys to act on:

```
String str = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^=]+)=([^,]+),?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String value = matcher.group(2);
    if("CN".equals(key) || "DC".equals(key)) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", key, value);
    }
}
```

> CN: FDCD111304
>   DC: FL
>   DC: NET

Comment: For your first idea,, does that mean if I change matcher.group(1) to matcher.group(4) if will output the Accounts?

Comment: No, the first idea will *only* get you the value of *CN*. `matcher.group(4)` will throw an exception. If you need more than one value use the second approach and only act on the keys that you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using substring to chop off the parts you dont require hence creating a new string

Answer (score -1):

There're few options, simples dumbest:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("=") + 1, str.indexOf(","))
```

Second one and more flexible approach would be to build HashArray, it would be helpful in future to read other values.

Edit: Second method

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String input = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\=(.*?)\\,");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

    while(m.find()) {

        String currentVar = m.group().substring(0, m.group().length() - 2);
        System.out.println(currentVar); //store or do whatever you want
    }
 }
}
```

This one will print all values like CN=FDCD11130, you can split it by '=' and store in key/value container like HashMap or just inside list.

Comment: This worked me pretty well sorta. I tweaked the substring to be like this  String currentVar = m.group().substring(3, m.group().length() - 1); and it outputs the computer name only on the first line, but it still shows the other stuff on other lines. I want the other stuff to be gone and not stored within the currentVar variable. See screenshot for reference. Also I updated code above.

Comment: After getting values from input you can split key/value by String#split method. Don't use hardcode indexes, you can search for first occurrence of CN key for example.